# Create a SharePoint web form and use LDAP to extract ActiveDirectory data

Tags: http, email, sharepoint, active-directory, sms

I would like to know how I might go about creating a SharePoint web form. The form will use LDAP to retrieve a user's mobile number from an ActiveDirectory server. Upon submission of the form, I will be able to send an email or HTTP request including the user's mobile number.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to interact with Active Directory directly? The best way to do this is to configure user profile synchronization from active directory and then get required field value from user profile.

Comment: Just a thought. I am not familiar with ActiveDirectory and SharePoint. How would I then go about linking the user profile synchronization with the web form?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is not to interact with AD directly.
You will need to configure [user profile synchronization](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx.) first. After that you can get user profiles using SharePoint Object Model, [UserProfileManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.aspx) class.